# Change default port number of unicorn using config/unicorn/unicorn.rb configs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

How can i change unicorn's default port number using config/unicorn/unicorn.rb file configuration parameters. I need to run two unicorns with nginx on same machine how can i achieve this? Right now i am getting port address already occupied error.

```
app_dir = "/home/rails/apps/app_name/current"
shared_dir = "/home/rails/apps/app_name/shared"

env = "staging"

# Set unicorn options
worker_processes 1
preload_app true
timeout 30

# Fill path to your app
working_directory app_dir

# Set up socket location
listen "#{shared_dir}/sockets/unicorn.admin.sock", :backlog => 64

# Loging
stderr_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

# Set master PID location
pid "#{shared_dir}/pids/unicorn.admin.pid"

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # server.listen(addr, :tries => -1, :delay => 5, :tcp_nopush => true)
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{app_dir}/Gemfile"
end
```

I am getting this error:

```
/shared/sockets/unicorn.admin.sock (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you use a socket-connection. In this case you have to use uniq entries for this line:

```
# Set up socket location
listen "#{shared_dir}/sockets/unicorn<X>.admin.sock", :backlog => 64
```

Comment: I am already using different entries 1. listen "#{shared_dir}/sockets/unicorn.admin.sock" and 2. listen "#{shared_dir}/sockets/unicorn.sock"

Comment: And you are shure that both `#{shared_dir}` are different? To me it looks like both point to `/shared/`. Or did you cut the folder name in your question?

Comment: Yes. both shared_dir's are different i had cut the parent folder.

Comment: When you use linux , you can use `fuser` to check which process is already using this socket. Maybe an older unicorn is running.